# Test if object is (sub)type of type stored in variable

Tags: swift, types

I need to test if an object is a (sub)type of type stored in a variable.

```
class Car {}
class RaceCar : Car {}
class Corvette : RaceCar {}
class Ferrari : RaceCar {}

var carType: Car.Type = RaceCar.self
var someCar: Car = Corvette()
if someCar is carType.Type { // <-- Cannot find type 'carType' in scope
    // someCar is from type or subtype of RaceCar
}
```

Please help me with declaring the type variable the right way and do the type test correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done, but it almost always indicates you have a deep design mistake.

If Foundation is imported, you can bridge AnyObject to NSObject and use `isKind(of:)`:

```
import Foundation
(someCar as AnyObject).isKind(of: carType)  // true
```

This will do what you ask. But it is ugly, and for good reason. This is relying heavily on inheritance, while breaking a key point of OOP, which is that subtypes should be [fully substitutable for their supertype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). If you need to start asking "which subtype are you," and particularly if you need to do that in a dynamic way, then you almost likely misusing class inheritance.

You probably want an enum here, or a protocol with a method, or even class overrides, rather than using inheritance this way. But it is possible to do what you ask.

Comment: I will try to find out if you're right with the hint to a design mistake - now i am really unsure if i am doing things right.